# Lightroom Adding some blue ovaerlay to my image, not sure what it is

Tags: lightroom

Lightroom Adding some blue ovaerlay to my image, not sure what it is, even in X/Y, I can see in both side, so it is not from my edits. Also when I go back to Library that blue color in foreground is gone. Looks like some setting in Light room I messed up, its happening with all my images, any idea what it is ?

[image: Comparison]